# VueJs 3 router.push() can't work in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

i want to click the button to remove the property of 'keyword' in query,and request data again

```
const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()
//watch router query change，send request to get data
watch(
  () => route.query,
  () => {
    //send request
    searchStore.getSearchList(route.query)
  },
  { immediate: true }
)
//remove keyword, update router , and refresh page
const removeKeyword = function () {
  route.query.keyword = undefined
  router.push({
    name: 'search',
    query: {...route.query}
  })
}
```

it seems no problem, but router can't update and page can't refresh,so that means router.push() didn't work and router query didn't been watched.
but when i add a new property in query,it works!

```
router.push({
  name: 'search',
  query: {...route.query，a: 1}
})
```

so i have to choose this way to solve the problem

```
const removeKeyword = function () {
  router.push({
    name: 'search',
    query: {...route.query, keyword: undefined}
  })
}
```

i wonder know why it is and if it have a better solution.
Has anyone can help me?

Comment: Don't use 'watch' for this. Move that 'watch' code into its own method, and then call the method on mount. Then, you can just call that method again anytime you want to get the new result, without having the refresh the page.

Comment: You mean delete watch and call method to get new data after update router?my idea is useing watch to get new data with query automaticlly.Watch will affect router.push()?The point is router.push() can't work

Comment: Yes, remove the 'watch', and use a 'method' instead, which is called on 'mount' of the component. The initial data will still be fetched automatically when you route to that page. You can then call the method again when you want to make another call for data, with different parameters. Try and get the idea of 'page refreshing' out of your head for this, it's not the way to go.

Comment: yes,i understand what you mean,your ways can get new data without refresh page. But i also want to change url when query changed. For example,initial url is '...?name=123&keyword=123' and i use `route.query.keyword = undefined` to remove that property, and want to get new url '...?name=123'. router.push() can do that.The problem is `router.push(name: 'search',query: {...route.query})` can't work，url not change.

Comment: amazing!!!!
`let temp = Object.assign({}, route.query)` 
`temp.keyword = undefined`
`router.push({
  name: 'search',
  query: temp,
})
`
it works. it's so weird

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJs 3 :vue-router change query and use router.push() but url don't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72997053/vuejs-3-vue-router-change-query-and-use-router-push-but-url-dont-update)