# VueJs 3 :vue-router change query and use router.push() but url don't update

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```
const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()
```

deep clone `route.query` and then change the property of new query,it works (url changes)

```
let newQuery = { ...route.query}
newQuery.keyword = undefined
router.push({
  name: 'search',
  query: newQuery,
})
```

but if I change property in `route.query` and then deep clone changed `route.query`,it cannot work (url not changes)

```
route.query.keyword = undefined
let newQuery = { ...route.query}
router.push({
 name: 'search',
 query: newQuery,
})
```

use `console.log(newQuery)` to check two newQuery, they are totally same.
It confuses me. I wonder why that is

Answer (score 2):

You should not change `route.query` directly. It is a readonly value and for changing it you should do `router.push({ ...route, query: { ...route.query, ...newQuery }})`

So the second approach is wrong and you should avoid it.

Comment: Oh, you mean `route.query` is readonly and immutable, i guess that's why watch can't detect when I change it directly. There is another question, after i change query directly and `console.log({...route.query})` I find value is changed, but `router.push()`  don't work.,it means value actually not changed. What's the reason behind such behaviour?

Comment: When you change the `route.query` directly, the value changes but the exact query of the page does not change. But with using `router.push()`, you go to a new URL with a new query and the `route.query` should change too. You can test it by setting a watch for `route.query` like this:

`router.push({ ...route , query: { ...route.query,  ...someQuery } }); watch(() => route.query, (newQuery) => { console.log(newQuery) })`

Comment: yes, I understand what you mean. But what bothers me now is, alter query before or after deepClone route.query, like`route.query.keyword = undefined; let newQuery = route.query` and `let newQuery = {...route.query}; newQuery.keyword = undefined`, I `console.log(newQuery)`, find they are totally same, as two common object, only the second `newQuery` works. Although route.query is readonly and immutable, I get my wanted query object parameter right?

Comment: Yes, you can get what you want from `route.query` and for changing it you should do it with `router.push`. I hope I could help you